# O que são schemas? Quais as vantagens de usá-lo?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, terminologia, sql-server-2012

Em quais situações o seu uso é recomendado?

Comment: Não consigo pensar em uma situação em que eles não sejam usados, mas mesmo assim, a pergunta é boa. +1.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## O que são Schemas?

São coleções de objetos dentro de um determinado banco de dados, que organizam vários aspectos e são importantes para segmentação da segurança, facilitando a administração dos objetos e dos dados.

A partir do SQL Server 2005, todo e qualquer objeto de banco de dados deixou de pertencer a um usuário para pertencer a um Schema. Sendo assim, o Schema é a ponte de associação entre o usuário (ou grupo de usuários) e um (ou mais) objeto(s) de banco.

## Quais as vantagens de usá-lo?

A primeira vantagem é o permissionamento de usuários e grupos. Quando um usuário é autorizado em um Schema, ele pode ser autorizado em vários bancos de dados ao mesmo tempo cujos objetos estejam inclusos dentro de um Schema.

A segunda vantagem é o agrupamento físico dos dados. Alguns servidores, como as versões mais recentes do SQL Server, permitem que objetos de um mesmo Schema, mesmo que estejam divididos em várias bases de dados, sejam agrupados fisicamente para administração de backups e carga.

## Em que situações o seu uso é recomendado?

Em bases de dados com múltiplos bancos de dados (que tenham vários sistemas, por exemplo) e seja necessário autorizar ou revogar usuários e grupos rapidamente.

Em bases de dados cujo permissionamento seja característica essencial para a segurança dos dados (sistemas antigos cliente-servidor, por exemplo, que dependem muito da base de dados para implementação das regras de negócio).

Em segmentação de dados por grupo de usuários. Você pode ter no mesmo database duas tabelas com o mesmo nome, estando cada uma em um Schema diferente.

Answer (score 13):

## O que são Schemas?

É um recipiente que podem conter vários objetos. São utilizados para gerir e organizar os objetos do banco de dados. Você consegue separar logicamente *procedures*, *views*, *triggers*, *sequences* e etc. Os objetos passam a pertencerem ao schema, assim as permissões são aplicadas aos schemas, dessa forma você pode dar permissões para usuários para que eles acessem somente os objetos que tem permissão de uma forma mais organizada.

#### Organização

O usuário X tem acesso a todos os objetos relacionados a empresa, nesta caso você teria que aplicar permissões a todos os objetos que ele tem acesso separadamente, exemplo:

No desenho abaixo, o usuário X teria acesso as tabelas funcionários e departamentos:

[image: Sem schema]

Usando schema para organizar, você daria permissão para o usuário X no schema empresa, exemplo:

[image: Com schema]

Os esquemas fornecem a oportunidade para simplificar a administração de segurança, backup / restauração e gestão de banco de dados, permitindo que os objetos de banco de dados, ou entidades, a ser logicamente agrupadas.

Fonte: [SQL Server Best Practices – Implementation of Database Object Schemas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Parabéns! Muito bem explicado através desse esboço! Me ajudou muito a entender!

Answer (score 3):

Estou aqui tentando fazer uma analogia para dar entendimento para programadores. Ele é parecido com um módulo ou *namespace*. Ele segrega alguma coisa do resto.

Inicialmente uma base de dados era suficiente para organizar tudo o que você precisava naquela solução. A base de dados era para banco de dados o que é a aplicação como um todo.

Da mesma forma que as aplicações foram ficando complexas e foi necessário desenvolver o conceito de módulos ou de *namespaces*, foi necessário criar algo que segregasse e agrupasse certas partes do modelo adotado de forma mais granular, daí nasceu o Schema.

Então em um Schema de uma base de dados você tem todo tipo de objeto típico de uma base dados, tabelas, índices, visões, gatilhos, etc. Mas como tem muita coisa e eventualmente quer ter na mesma ou outras bases de dados, outras partes que são coesas estarem juntas, mas são tão distintas de outros objetos que você os segrega como se estivesse colocando em outra base dados, ou agrupa o que vem de bases diferentes.

Assim como um *namespace* pode ter elementos de módulos/arquivos/pacotes diferentes, um Schema pode conter bases de dados diferentes também. O Schema é um agrupamento lógico e não físico (nenhuma fonte que eu achei corrobora que seja físico), ao contrário da base de dados que costuma ser física (há tecnologias que usam outras formas de organização física como *tablespaces*).

Tanto não é físico que ele não tem dados, ele não pode ser confundido com a base de dados. Ele é uma planta baixa, um mapa, do que teria na(s) base(s) de dados. Ele é o oposto, ele permite que algo fisicamente separado possa ser tratado logicamente como uma coisa só.

É possível aplicar o conceito de Schema em instâncias conceituais diferentes relatadas em [Qual a diferença entre modelagem conceitual, lógica e física?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/565764/101). Mas mesmo na aplicação física, ele não é um agrupamento físico, é algo lógico aplicado ao físico.

Uma das vantagens é que você pode usar nomes iguais em Schemas diferentes já que ele fornece um sobrenome para os nomes evitando a ambiguidade.

Mas a maior vantagem é poder administrar todo esse conjunto como uma coisa só, porém diferenciado do que faz com outros objetos em outro Schema que precisa de uma política diferente. Ele é como se criasse um grupo, você coloca o que quiser no grupo, mas o correto é colocar o que deve ser tratado com coesão entre todos seus membros.

Boa parte do que se faz em banco de dados não necessita dele obrigatoriamente, mas algumas tecnologias te obrigam usar de qualquer forma.

Em alguns bancos de dados ele acaba funcionando como proprietário dos objetos, o que reforça a ideia de grupo e portanto quando for fazer algo com os objetos de um Schema o faz através do Schema. É o caso do SQL Server.

Um dos exemplos mais óbvios dessa organização é para dar permissão para usuários em todo o bloco. Especialmente no SQL Server é como se o Schema fosse o proprietário dos objetos e o usuário passa ter permissão ao Schema, recebendo tudo o que tem dentro do bloco.

## Vantagens

- Acesso e segurança: o *design* do Schema de banco de dados ajuda a organizar os dados em entidades separadas, facilitando o compartilhamento de um único esquema em outro banco de dados. Os administradores também podem controlar o acesso por meio de permissões de banco de dados, adicionando outra camada de segurança para dados mais proprietários. Por exemplo, um único esquema pode conter informações de identificação pessoal (PII), que você deseja criptografar para fins de privacidade e segurança.
- Organização e comunicação: A documentação de Schemas de banco de dados permite mais organização e melhor comunicação entre as partes interessadas internas. Como ele fornece uma fonte comum de verdade, ele permite que os usuários entendam as restrições lógicas e os métodos de agregação entre tabelas.
- Integridade: Esta organização e comunicação também ajudam a garantir a validade dos dados. Por exemplo, pode ajudar os administradores a gerenciar os processos de normalização para evitar a duplicação de dados. Também pode auxiliar no monitoramento da conformidade das restrições no *design* do banco de dados do Schema, permitindo a aderência às propriedades ACID (atomicidade, consistência, isolamento, durabilidade).

## Conclusão

A resposta do abfurlan é boa e está correta, tanto que eu já havia votado, eu quis aqui dar uma visão diferente e evitar o entendimento equivocado em parte da resposta aceita.
[image: Modelo da Wikipedia]
[Fonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema). Lá mostra uma forma mais acadêmica de ver o assunto e acho que você deveria ler.

Há um entendimento um pouco diferente do termo acadêmico e como ele é aplicado em bancos de dados relacionais (SQL), especialmente no SQL Server.