# Qual a diferença entre modelagem conceitual, lógica e física?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, modelagem, modelo-relacional, entidade-relacionamento

Em banco de dados relacional, qual a diferença entre modelagem conceitual, lógica e física?

Poderia dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Modelagem Conceitual

O objetivo aqui é criar um modelo de forma gráfica, sendo este chamado de Diagrama Entidade e Relacionamento (DER), que identificará todas as entidades e relacionamentos de uma forma global.
Aqui é evitado qualquer detalhamento específico do modelo de BD.
Sua principal finalidade é capturar os requisitos de informação e regras de negócio sob o ponto de vista do negócio.
No desenvolvimento de soluções é o primeiro modelo que deve ser desenvolvido.
Na fase de levantamento de requisitos.
Feito geralmente pelo Gestor de Dados de Negócio ou outro profissional  acompanhado de sua supervisão/orientação.
É independente de hardware ou software, ou seja, não depende de nenhum tipo de servidor de banco de dados [Sql Server, My Sql, Oracle, Postgresql, etc].
Por tanto, qualquer alteração no software ou hardware, não terão efeito no nível conceitual.

#### Modelagem lógica

A modelagem lógica é necessária para compilar os requisitos de negócio e representar os requisitos como um modelo.
Está principalmente associada à coleta de necessidades de negócios, e não ao design do banco de dados.
As informações que precisam ser coletadas são sobre unidades organizacionais, entidades de negócios e processos de negócios.
Descreve como os dados serão armazenados no banco e também seus relacionamentos.
Esse modelo adota alguma tecnologia, pode ser: relacional, orientado a objetos, orientado a colunas, entre outros.

Os modelos lógicos basicamente determinam se todos os requisitos do negócio foram reunidos.
Ele é revisado pelos desenvolvedores, pelo gerenciamento e, por fim, pelos usuários finais para ver se é necessário coletar mais informações antes do início da modelagem física.

O DER lógico também modela as informações coletadas dos requisitos de negócios.
É mais complexo do que o modelo conceitual em que os tipos de coluna são definidos.
Observe que a configuração dos tipos de coluna é opcional e, se você fizer isso, deverá fazer isso para auxiliar na análise de negócios.
Não tem nada a ver com a criação de banco de dados ainda.

#### Modelagem física

A modelagem física lida com o design do banco de dados real com base nos requisitos reunidos durante a modelagem lógica do banco de dados.
Todas as informações coletadas são convertidas em modelos relacionais e modelos de negócios.
Durante a modelagem física, os objetos são definidos em um nível denominado nível de esquema.
Um esquema é considerado um grupo de objetos que estão relacionados entre si em um banco de dados.
Tabelas e colunas são feitas de acordo com as informações fornecidas durante a modelagem lógica.
Chaves primárias, chaves exclusivas e chaves estrangeiras são definidas para fornecer restrições.
Índices são definidos.

A modelagem física depende do software que já está sendo usado na organização.
É específica ao software. [Sql Server, Oracle, MySql, Postgresql, etc]

#### Resumo:#

1. Entre os componentes de um modelo conceitual, podemos relacionar:

- Entidades;
- Atributos;
- Relacionamentos;

2. Modelagem lógica é principalmente para a coleta de informações sobre as necessidades de negócios e não envolve projetar um banco de dados.
   Enquanto que a modelagem física é principalmente necessária para o projeto real do banco de dados.
3. Modelagem lógica não inclui índices e constraints.
   O modelo lógico para um aplicativo pode ser usado em vários banco de dados [Sql Server, MySql, Oracle, Postgresql, etc].
   Na modelagem lógica pode haver chaves primárias e estrangeiras, qnquanto que a modelagem física é específica de software e hardware e possui  índices e constraints.
4. Modelagem lógica inclui; ERD, diagramas de processos de negócios e documentação de feedback do usuário; considerando que a modelagem física inclui; diagrama de modelo de servidor, documentação de design de banco de dados e documentação de feedback do usuário.

---

Traduzido de: http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/software-technology/difference-between-logical-and-physical-database-model/

---

## Tabela comparativa das características dos modelos

Nesta tabela você pode ver a diferença entre cada modelo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## Exemplo detalhado de um Modelo Conceitual

Exemplo de um DER – Diagrama de Entidade e Relacionamento

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De: http://spaceprogrammer.com/bd/introducao-ao-modelo-de-dados-e-seus-niveis-de-abstracao/

---

## Comparativo de diversas formas de representar um Modelo Conceitual

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## Exemplo de modelagem de um sistema com os 3 modelos

**modelo conceitual**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**modelo lógico**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**modelo físico**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagens de: http://www.fabiodomingues.com.br/modelagem-de-banco-de-dados/

---

## Outra forma de modelar um sistema com os 3 modelos

Traduzido de: https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/3563/3564/85378_conceptual,l.html

**DER - modelo conceitual**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**DER - modelo lógico**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**DER - modelo físico**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## Mais uma exemplo comparando os 3 modelos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## Exemplo de um modo de Modelagem Física

Um modelo físico pode ser constituído de código SQL para criação de objetos no banco

```
CREATE TABLE turma (
  idturma INTEGER(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  capacidade INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
  idProfessor INTEGER(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idturma),
  FOREIGN KEY (idProfessor) REFERENCES professor(idProfessor),
  UNIQUE KEY idturma (idturma)
)

CREATE TABLE professor (
  idProfessor INTEGER(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  telefone INTEGER(10) NOT NULL,
  nome CHAR(80) COLLATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (idProfessor),
  FOREIGN KEY(idTurma) REFERENCES turma(idturma),
  UNIQUE KEY idProfessor (idProfessor)
)
```

---

Links [origens]:

http://spaceprogrammer.com/bd/introducao-ao-modelo-de-dados-e-seus-niveis-de-abstracao/

http://www.blrdata.com.br/single-post/2016/03/19/Modelagem-Conceitual-de-Dados-Conhe%C3%A7a-os-principais-conceitos-e-pr%C3%A1ticas

https://www.luis.blog.br/modelagem-conceitual-modelo-conceitual-de-dados

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelagem_de_dados

http://www.diegomacedo.com.br/modelagem-conceitual-logica-e-fisica-de-dados

Comment: Alterei a pergunta para pedir um exemplo das duas.

Comment: @Piovezan, coloquei exemplo e uma tabela comparativa

Comment: Tem modelo conceitual também? Podia rolar uma explicada nele hein ;)

Comment: @Piovezan, adicionei maiores detalhes, e também sobre modelo conceitual, na pergunta, você poderia mudar também, adicionando no título e no texto a menção ao modelo conceitual.

Comment: Na tabela comparativa dos três modelos acho que a linha "Atributos" deve ser tickada na coluna "Conceitual", concorda? P.S.: Reputaçãozinha suada pra conseguir, diz aí... desculpe a trabalheira :)

Comment: ehehe... deu bastante trabalho até agora, mas uma coisa muito boa é que também estou relembrando muita coisa e aprendi outras também.

Comment: @Piovezan, corrigi a tabela e adicionei mais um diagrama com os 3 modelos

Comment: Olá Danilo, você conhece algum livro que fale sobre esses conceitos? Já olhei no índice de alguns livros mas só vejo modelo entidade-relacionamento e modelo relacional, seria isso?

Comment: @Piovezan, tenho o livo da Editora Campus, Elsevier, de Paulo Cougo, Modelagem Conceitual e Projeto de Banco de Dados, mas ele só fala de modelos conceituais, o restante consegui via aplicativos como o ERwin, visual-paradigm, e com o Enterprise Architect que possuí uma excelente documentação, da para instalar a versão trial. O que você achou foi MER com modelos conceituais?

Comment: @Piovezan, a diferença entre os modelos Conceitual, Lógico e Físico está no nível de abstração, e cada ferramenta utiliza uma notação para esses modelos, tem esse link com uma ótima explicação: https://www.zachman.com/ea-articles-reference/58-conceptual-logical-physical-it-is-simple-by-john-a-zachman

Comment: @Piovezan, um outro aplicativo com uma ótima documentação é o Sybase Powerdesign

Answer (score 7):

Passando uma visão um pouco diferente.

Os modelos conceitual e lógico são muito parecidos, por isso é comum partir para o lógico sem passar pelo conceitual. Ambos são gerais e são pensados sem preocupação com eficiência ou em que sistema gerenciador de banco de dados será implementado. O conceitual é um pouco mais geral que o lógico. O modelo físico é mais detalhado e considera onde o modelo vai rodar.

Para efeito de desenvolvimento da aplicação o físico não é muito considerado em primeiro momento. Em alguns casos o físico pode ser igual ao lógico, em termos de estrutura, mas pode precisar mudar para atender a necessidade do SGDB ou para alcançar alguma meta de eficiência. Ele é o que importa na hora de implementar.

Não é incomum que o desenvolvimento acabe sendo feito em cima do físico e o lógico é que se adapta :) Até porque fica menos burocrático.

O que se considera é que o modelo conceitual é para mostrar O QUE fazer. Fazendo uma analogia com programação, seria a forma declarativa.

O modelo lógico seria o COMO fazer. O problema é que ainda se faz de forma declarativa, então não é como na programação que seria a forma imperativa, só muda um pouco o detalhamento.

A maior diferença entre os dois é que o lógico tem dados mais técnicos, por exemplo o tipo do dado, o tamanho que ele comporta, e eventualmente alguma restrição de como o dado pode ser. O conceitual só precisa saber quais são os dados de forma geral sem pensar em nada técnico, você precisa saber que em uma entidade terá os atributos x, y, e z, como as entidades se relacionam, e mais nada.

O modelo conceitual é para conversar com o pessoal de negócios, que nada entendem de tecnologia.

Geralmente aplica-se no modelo lógico alguma [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101), que pode eventualmente ser desfeita no modelo físico se for importante. Há quem ache que as chaves já devem ser aplicadas aqui, mas provavelmente não de forma técnica, não como otimização.

No modelo físico colocará tudo o que é necessário para criar as tabelas no SGDB, não só das colunas, mas sobre [chaves](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277091/101), [índices](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183305/101), [gatilhos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164400/101) e restrições mais técnicas, inclusive de permissões de acesso. Até mesmo *views*, que curiosamente ajuda a entregar mais próximo do modelo lógico, inclusive algumas pessoas pregam que o acesso só deveria ser feito por *views* (tipo a recomendação de usar *getter/setter* e não o campo direto).

Note que exatamente o que deve ir em cada modelo varia de autor para autor. Você tem que ver o que é melhor para você e se precisa trabalhar todas as camadas de modelagem ou não. A única obrigatória é a física. Com duas ou três camadas terá que mudar em lugares diferentes sempre que mudar qualquer pequeno detalhe.

## Contraponto da outra resposta

A resposta do danilo é o que um autor explica, não de todos. Eu torço o nariz pra tudo que tem versões diferentes do que é o certo a fazer, até porque não é nem questão de contexto. O contexto é só se você vive em ambiente mais burocrático ou não, que tem vantagens e desvantagens.

Eu não gosto da ideia de que o modelo conceitual não tenha atributos de forma bem básica, acho que sem isso é quase uma camada mais alta ainda, ajuda muito pouco. O conceitual pode não ter todos os atributos, pode não ter a mesma estrutura, mas eu acho que precisa dar uma ideia geral dos dados que constarão ali. Pode até criar atributos virtuais como um "endereço" em vez de cada parte do endereço.

Mas eu admito que essa ideia mais simples do modelo conceitual é mais divulgada e adotada, e a resposta não está errada, longe disto.

O modelo não depende de representação gráfica alguma, mas é muito comum usar diagramas consagrados para demonstrar isto. Nesse ponto não gosto da outra resposta porque ela induz a que o modelo e a representação gráfica são a mesma coisa.

## Meu uso

Uma forma que eu mesmo já adotei foi fazer o conceitual uma vez, pular para o físico e nunca mais voltar ao conceitual. Ou seja, o conceitual é um rascunho básico para começar, mas não para documentar e manter. E já tive projeto em que o lógico tinha papel importante, e justamente as *views* eram muito usadas.

## Conclusão

Eu queria dar uma forma diferente de ver, ainda que eu tenha gostado da outra resposta. E por isso resolvi não detalhar tanto aqui, é mais uma visão alternativa.

O modelo conceitual é muito alto nível, quase um rascunho, pouco necessário de fato, principalmente se ele não tiver algum detalhe, e a grande diferença entre o lógico e físico é sobre ser ideal e ser pragmático, o que é a visão adequada e o que precisa por na tecnologia pra funcionar bem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Gostei da tua complementação, Maniero. Senti apenas de mencionar que vejo os *modelos Conceitual e Lógico* tendo papel importante em casos que a própria definição do negócio ainda está em desenvolvimento e, portanto, o processo acontece mais interativamente. Se considerarmos uma abordagem API-first, por exemplo, se pode amadurecer e inclusive implementar diversos pontos da aplicação, tomando um bom tempo pra chegar no modelo físico, enquanto um modelo lógico serve de base pra essa evolução!